# Logstash double flow in and out of S3 bucket

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, amazon-s3, logstash, filebeat

I am setting up a Kubernetes application log to be stored in S3 and be analyzed with ElasticSearch/Kibana.

I've found [this article](https://www.chaossearch.io/blog/how-to-move-kubernetes-logs-to-s3-logstash) which describes how to push logs from Kubernetes to S3 using Filebeat and Logstash.

In there one is setting Logstash `input` as being Filebeat and `output` as being S3, which is fine at this point.

The question I have is how would I set up Logstash to access the S3 bucket for analysis. In this instance the `input` would be the S3 bucket and the `output` would be ElasticSearch.

Putting it all together, I would have `input` as being either Filebeat or S3 and `output` as being one of S3 or ElasticSearch.

Not knowing much about Logstash I do not know if that's possible and how to go about it.

How can I build a working setup where the information flows through Logstash in both directions above and what would the Logstash configuration be?